# How do I remove / hide source control notifications in VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I remove or hide the blue circle notification thing that has 3 in it in the picture below?

I want to keep the `source control` feature, but I can't stand the notification always being there every time I write some code.

[image]

Comment: watching this thread for answer - it bugs me as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This *Count Badge* setting should do the trick:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off the `Count Badge` from here - **File > Preferences > Settings > SCM**. Shortcut to reach the same setting: `Ctrl + ,`

[image]